# wp query to search string and taxonomy doesnt work when search only with string variable,how to resolve?

Tags: wordpress

```
$search_name = !empty($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';$search_term_id = !empty($_POST['term_id']) ? $_POST['term_id'] : '';
$args => array
            (
                'post_type'=>'ourteam',
                'post_status'=>'publish',
                's' => $search_name,
                'tax_query' => array
                    (
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array //Search Tag
                            (
                                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                                'field' => 'term_id',
                                'terms' => $search_term_id
                            ),                
                     ),
           );
$the_query=new WP_Query($args);
```

The above code works fine when searching with the `term_id` only and string + `term_id` term but when the search is done with the string variable it doesn't display the content.

How to solve this problem?? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code? You haven't defined `$search_term_id` or `$search_name`

Comment: $search_name = !empty($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';            $search_term_id = !empty($_POST['term_id']) ? $_POST['term_id'] : ''; post value were sent from the ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i checked the condition for the empty term_id like

```
if (!empty($search_term_id)) {
    $tax_query = array
                (
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                   'terms' => $search_term_id
                );    
}
$args => array
            (
                'post_type'=>'ourteam',
                'post_status'=>'publish',
                's' => $search_name,
                'tax_query' => array
                                  (
                                      $tax_query,
                                  ),
           );
$the_query=new WP_Query($args);
```

This solved my problem.anyway thankyou for your response

Answer (score 1):

Do not use 'relation' with a single inner taxonomy array. 
Similar code which is working:

```
$search_name = 'Watch';
$term_id     = '21';
    $args = array
            (
                'post_type'=>'product',
                'post_status'=>'publish',
                's' => $search_name,
                'tax_query' => array
                    (
            array //Search Tag
                            (
                                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                'field' => 'term_id',
                                'terms' => $term_id
                            ),                
                     ),
           );
$the_query=new WP_Query($args);
```

Check values stored in variables, post type, taxonomy and post status.

Comment: This work fine but it doesnt work when $term_id is empty. when search with the search_name only,displays nothing i need to met both conditions for the multiple search. Thank you

Comment: i need search by search_name only,search by search_name and term_id, term_id only .i used ajax but it works fine only when term_id is given.when term_id not given displays nothing.Thanks