# WP_Query: Search by Taxonomy Name

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

Problem: `WP_Query` search string needs to look into the taxonomy name.

By default, `$args['s']` only searches inside the title, content, and excerpt, but I need to search inside a custom taxonomy name too. I tried with `tax_query,` but it doesn't have the [`name__like` or `LIKE` operator](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/133777) for `tax_query`.

So, Now I'm trying to achieve it with the custom query; here's my code:

```
$keyword = "Monster";
$args['s'] = $keyword;


add_filter('posts_join', 'filter_post_join', 10, 1);
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_post_where', 10, 1);

$posts = new WP_Query($args);



function filter_post_join( $join ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $join .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships as txr ON ( {$wpdb->posts}.ID = txr.object_id )";
    $join .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms as trms on ( txr.term_taxonomy_id = trms.term_id )";

    return $join;
}

function filter_post_where( $where ) {
   
    global $keyword;

    $where .= " AND trms.name LIKE $keyword";
    return $where;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

I found a solution that kind of works: https://gist.github.com/markoman78/e22bbebe0d2305f294eb554d5a39d8c3

But it has a problem, it doesn't filter `post_type`; if I want to fetch posts from 'x' post type it will also fetch posts from other posts type that has matching tags name

Comment: Let's see the generated SQL.

Comment: I found a solution that kind of works: https://gist.github.com/markoman78/e22bbebe0d2305f294eb554d5a39d8c3

But it has a problem, it doesn't filter `post_type`; if I want to fetch posts from 'x' post type it will also fetch posts from other posts type that has matching tags name

Comment: "post_type" is not mentioned in your Question.

Comment: Perhaps this will help:  [_WP Index Improvements_](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)

Comment: why not define the post type in the WP_Query? and then add the filters to that.

Comment: Seems like a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431062/wp-query-to-search-string-and-taxonomy-doesnt-work-when-search-only-with-string Hope this helps!